# get average of last 2 entries from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get average of last 2 entries from elastic search but stuck in this. below is my data in elastic search:

```
{
    "took": 115,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 22696195,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [{
                "_index": "queue_pings",
                "_type": "QueuePings",
                "_id": "AWGtuVzycUtYPYuAwOzr",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "queue": "queue1",
                    "length": 134,
                    "timestamp": "2018-02-19 11:01:01"
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "queue_pings",
                "_type": "QueuePings",
                "_id": "AWGtuV0DcUtYPYuAwOzs",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "queue": "queue2",
                    "length": 1202,
                    "timestamp": "2018-02-19 11:01:01"
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "queue_pings",
                "_type": "QueuePings",
                "_id": "AWGtuV0dWFpRPa9T9mcf",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "queue": "queue1",
                    "length": 120,
                    "timestamp": "2018-02-19 11:00:01"
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "queue_pings",
                "_type": "QueuePings",
                "_id": "AWGtuV0wTPjiqgqsDMAM",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "queue": "queue2",
                    "length": 1762,
                    "timestamp": "2018-02-19 11:00:01"
                }
            }, {
                "_index": "queue_pings",
                "_type": "QueuePings",
                "_id": "AWGtuV09WFpRPa9T9mcg",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "queue": "queue3",
                    "length": 220,
                    "timestamp": "2018-02-19 11:00:01"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get average of last 2 entries where `queue = queue1`.

Here is equivalent MYSQL query `SELECT AVG(length) FROM queue_pings WHERE queue = 'queue1' order by timestamp desc limit 2;`

What i have tried so far:

```
GET /queue_pings/_search?size=2
{
  "aggs": {
    "queue_filter" : {
      "filter" : { "term" : { "queue" : "queue1" } },
      "aggs" : {
        "queue_avg" : { "avg" : { "field" : "length" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding mapping

```
{
  "queue_pings": {
    "mappings": {
      "QueuePings": {
        "properties": {
          "length": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "queue": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "ignore_malformed": true,
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in Elasticsearch in a query.
The idea is kind of a two step process:
- first get the maximum date (the latest one), like a MAX aggregation if you'd like
- then get the first two documents "smaller" than this latest date, which is basically a `top_hits` aggregation

And you cannot apply an aggregation (the AVG) on the results of a `top_hits`. And the same you cannot do if you limit your results to 2 then do the average, because it will match more documents, do the AVG on them then give you only two.

Anyway, in my opinion, the simplest solution is to do

```
{
   "size": 2,
   "sort":[
      {
         "timestamp":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query":{
        "term":{
            "queue.keyword":"queue1"
        }
    }
}
```

and then calculate the average yourself, after you get the two results back. It's a simple operation you can do outside Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i'm already using this in my code but looking for improvement (or direct way to do this). once again Thanks you!.